# SPARQL Query with filtering over an integer

Tags: sparql, wikipedia-api

I am writing a very straightforward sparql query that filter an integer value.

I figured it out through [this tutorial](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/)
I know that Wikipedia Id = 856 is for apple_inc but this query doesn’t give any results, I don’t know what I am missing. Any help would be appreciated.

```
select ?uri where {?uri <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageID> ?id. FILTER regex(?id, "856"^^xsd:integer, "i")}
```

Comment: regex does not allow a number in the second argument => type error =>filter false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write it like this:

```
select ?uri where {?uri <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageID> ?id. FILTER (?id=856)}
```

Comment: Conceptually this has to select *all* the page id triples, then filter out all but the right one.  (Implementations *should* make the process more efficient though.)  It's much clearer to just put the value right in the query and skip the filter altogether: `select ?uri where {?uri <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageID> 856 .}`

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason to use **filter** here at all.  Conceptually a **filter** has to select all the page id triples, then filter out all but the right one. (Implementations should make the process more efficient though.)

It's much clearer to just put the value right in the query and skip the filter altogether:

```sql
select ?uri where {
  ?uri <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageID> 856
}
```